# Spacing between leftbarbuttonitems

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

Trying to add 2 buttons on the left, but having some issues with the spacing. Any solutions? I tried negative spacing but it doesn't work. It is just 2 normal buttons initiated with:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[self.menuButton, self.scoreLabel];
```

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is your issue is the spacing? too far or too close?

Comment: The space between the menu and 2724 is too large

Comment: and why don't put the 2427 into segment _trending_ or _recent_ which it belongs to? or what should that number represent actually in the title? (I am just asking you because your issue looks to be related to a poorly design UI rather than a simple spacing issue between the items).

Comment: the number is a "score" which is separate. (imagine how yik yak is but with a menu button on top as well)

Comment: @John have you tried with titleEdgeInsets of UIButton?

Answer (score 2):

Create a UIBarButtonItem, for example

```
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

set the width of spacer as

```
spacer.width = -15.0f;
```

Add this spacer between your self.menuButton and self.scoreLabel objects as shown below,

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[self.menuButton ,spacer , self.scoreLabel];
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, I tried negative spacing already, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your score button width by giving it a background color or the button title may be right aligned. Otherwise negative spacing works well.

```
//Create a  bar button with negative spacing 
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -15.0f;

//Bar Button 1
UIImage *sideImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"];
UIButton *btnSideMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnSideMenu setImage:sideImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSideMenu setImage:sideImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnSideMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sideImage.size.width, sideImage.size.height)];
[btnSideMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLeftMenuClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *sideMenuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSideMenu];

//Bar Button 2
UIImage *sideImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"];
UIButton *btnSideMenu1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnSideMenu1 setImage:sideImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSideMenu1 setImage:sideImage1 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnSideMenu1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sideImage1.size.width, sideImage1.size.height)];
[btnSideMenu1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLeftMenuClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *sideMenuItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSideMenu1];

//Add all the bar buttons in the leftBarButtonItems Array
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sideMenuItem1, negativeSpacer, sideMenuItem, nil];
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. it works perfectly. So i have upvoted you. Thanks a lot.